# Set different SelectionChanged Event Handler for a DataGrid inside another DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid, toolkit

I have a DataGrid (WPF Toolkit) with a custom combobox like edit template of a cell. This custom combo box have another datagrid like popup.

I have this problem:

In the window constructor I assign the event handler to the master datagrid with this statement

`this.dgDoc.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(dgDoc_SelectionChanged);`

the problem is that the function dgDoc_SelectionChanged fire also when I change selection on datagrid of combobox popup.

How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the events are bubbling up the tree and are finding a handler. bummer.

why dont you just check who the **sender** is and if it is the inner grid, ignore them, if it is the grid you are interested in handle them

Comment: I try but the sender is always the master datagrid...also if the event is fired by combobox datagrid. Is strange.

Comment: can you replicate it in a test project?